# Copying books using dynamic programming

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I am implementing the dynamic programming solution for copying books problem. The idea for the solution is taken from [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~hsinmu/courses/_media/ada_13fall/midterm2013_sol.pdf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680188/copying-books-uva-online-judge-dynamic-programing-solution).

Problem statement:

> Before the invention of book-printing, it was very hard to make a copy
>   of a book. All the contents had to be re-written by hand by so called
>   scribers. The scriber had been given a book and after several months
>   he finished its copy. One of the most famous scribers lived in the
>   15th century and his name was Xaverius Endricus Remius Ontius
>   Xendrianus (Xerox). Anyway, the work was very annoying and boring. And
>   the only way to speed it up was to hire more scribers.
>
> Once upon a time, there was a theater ensemble that wanted to play
>   famous Antique Tragedies. The scripts of these plays were divided into
>   many books and actors needed more copies of them, of course. So they
>   hired many scribers to make copies of these books. Imagine you have m
>   books (numbered 1, 2, ...., m) that may have different number of pages
>   ( p_1, p_2, ..., p_m) and you want to make one copy of each of them.
>   Your task is to divide these books among k scribes, k <= m. Each book
>   can be assigned to a single scriber only, and every scriber must get a
>   continuous sequence of books. That means, there exists an increasing
>   succession of numbers 0 = b_0 < b_1 < b_2, ... < b_{k-1} <= b_k = m$
>   such that i-th scriber gets a sequence of books with numbers between
>   bi-1+1 and bi. The time needed to make a copy of all the books is
>   determined by the scriber who was assigned the most work. Therefore,
>   our goal is to minimize the maximum number of pages assigned to a
>   single scriber. Your task is to find the optimal assignment.

I am able to obtain the optimal solution for the problem described iteratively, but unable to use that to find the required solution for the problem, that is:

```
Sample input:
2
9 3
100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
5 4
100 100 100 100 100

Sample Output
100 200 300 400 500 / 600 700 / 800 900
100 / 100 / 100 / 100 100
```

Where 2 is the number of datasets, 9 is the number of books and 3 is the number of scribes to assign the books to.

Here is my output, for the respective inputs:

```
100 100 100 
300 300 300 
600 600 600 
1000 700 700 
1500 900 900 
2100 1100 1100 
2800 1300 1300 
3600 1500 1500 
4500 1700 1700 

100 100 100 100 
200 200 200 200 
300 300 300 300 
400 300 300 300 
500 300 300 300
```

For the first solution set, I can use 1700 as the optimal number of page assignments to each user and keep on assigning the book pages until, Current scribe page sum >= 1700. However, the second solution does not have any pattern to it whatsoever?

Here is my code to generate the solution:

```
private void processScribes(){
        int[][] bookScribe = new int[numOfBooks][numOfScribes];
        //set first row to b1 page number
        for (int j = 0; j < numOfScribes; ++j)
            bookScribe[0][j] = bookPages[0];

        //set first column to sum of book page numbers
        for (int row = 1; row < numOfBooks; ++row)
            bookScribe[row][0] = bookScribe[row - 1][0] + bookPages[row]; 

        //calculate the kth scribe using dp
        for (int i = 1; i < numOfBooks; ++i){
            for (int j = 1; j < numOfScribes; ++j){
                //calculate minimum of maximum page numbers
                //from k = l + 1 to i
                //calculate sum 
                int minValue = 1000000;
                for (int k = 0; k < i - 1; ++k){
                    int prevValue = bookScribe[i - k][j - 1];
                    int max = 0;
                    int sumOflVals = 0;
                    for (int l = k + 1; l <= i; ++l){
                        sumOflVals = sumOflVals + bookPages[l];
                    }
                    if (prevValue > sumOflVals){
                        max = prevValue;
                    }
                    else
                        max = sumOflVals;
                    if (max < minValue )
                        minValue = max;
                }
                if (minValue == 1000000)
                    minValue = bookScribe[i][0];
                //store minvalue at [i][j]
                bookScribe[i][j] = minValue;
            }
        }

        //print bookScribes
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfBooks; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfScribes; ++j)
                System.out.print(bookScribe[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Any pointers here? Is it the interpretation of solution or something is wrong with how I am translating the recurrence in my code?

Comment: whats your question exactly also it would be really helpful if you included the problem statement in the beginning

Comment: @sasha question is provided in the hyperlink attached with the problem.

Comment: yes read it know could you tell what exactly the problem is ? is it in coding/ finding explanation for a testcase / coming up with a dp solution. Also generally the question should be self contained without the links, links should be for further reference or detailed explanation

Comment: @faizanjehangir Hyperlinks tend to die. Please post a short explanation of the problem statement in the question itself.

Comment: @amit I have added more details about the problem statement and question itself

Comment: also is it necessary that each subscriber have atleast one book to copy ?

Comment: Yes, each scriber, should be atleast assigned one book.

Comment: what you are doing seems to be a greedy solution

Comment: No, I am pretty sure this is a DP solution. Each kth calculation is made using the saved results..

Comment: I think you should interpret it as parallel processors (scribers), the problem is to minimize the time to finish the tasks (each book) which has a time to be proccessed (number of pages). Doing this, the problem got easier to implement.

Comment: @AdolAurion the problem is to give the optimal assignment for the number of pages to each scriber. So that no scriber is working too much that any other scriber available.

Comment: @faizanjehangir That's what i said... the optimal assignment is the minimal time to finish, because I interpret the number of pages as time...

Comment: Parallel processing in DP? How can I compute kth scriber without having a result for k-1?

Comment: @faizanjehangir I think you didn't read my answer. I said "to interpret it as parallel processors", not "to implement it with parallel processors"

Comment: @faizanjehangir I know my answer does not find mistake in your code but I have tried to give an intuitive recursive approach with memoizatio/dp . hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of your solution but here is an intuitive recursive approach with memoization. Let there be **n** books with ith book having **pages[i]** pages. Also let there be **m** subscribers. Also let **dp[i][j]** be the answer to problem if we were given only books **i,i+1.....n** and there are only **j** subscribers to do the job. Following is a recursive pseudo code with memoization

```
    //dp[][] is memset to -1 from main
    // Assuming books are numbered 1 to n
    // change value of MAX based on your constraints
    int MAX = 1000000000;
    int rec(int position , int sub )
    {
          // These two are the base cases
          if(position > n)
          {
             if(sub == 0)return 0;
             return MAX;
          }
          if(sub == 0)
          {
              if(position > n)return 0;
              return MAX;
          }

          // If answer is already computed for this state return it
          if(dp[position][sub] != -1)return dp[position][sub];

          int ans = MAX,i,sum = 0;
          for(i = position; i <= n;i++)
          {
             sum += pages[i];
             // taking the best of all possible solutions
             ans = min(ans,max(sum,rec(i+1,sub-1)));
          }
          dp[position][sub]=ans;
          return ans; 
    }

    //from main call rec(1,m) which is your answer
```

You can convert it to an iterative solution by dynamic programming it will be same complexity in time and space .Space is **O(n.m)** and time is **O(n^2.m)**.

**EDIT** 
Here have a look at running version of the code on your testcases [Book Copying Code](http://ideone.com/e.js/nIJ6QZ) . It not only finds optimal answer but also prints the optimal assignment with it ( which I have not included in the pseudo code above). ( click on the top right corner fork and it would run on
your testcases, input format is same as yours ). Output will optimal answer followed by optimal assignment. Do comment if you have doubts regarding the code.

Comment: Can you explain the use of `sub` in this procedure?

Comment: sub means number of subscribers

Comment: position means considering only book from postion,position+1...n. See the definition of my dp[][] array it explains both position ( i ) and sub ( j ).

Comment: @faizanjehangir Look at my EDIT and go to the link of working version of code

Comment: the indices are a little confusing, but the solution is perfect!

Comment: If you have doubt I can explain , yes I got bit clumpsy with variable names at the end of the code sorry for that